# Tastypie error working with Django 1.5 custom User model.

Tags: django, tastypie

Hi I keep getting the error

```
ImportError at /account/signup/

cannot import name username_field

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/account/signup/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

cannot import name username_field

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie      /authentication.py in <module>, line 13
```

I have looked at this fix [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/commit/b8f4b9cad4256df2d657bf5f5162e526886301f4)  although I am unable to resolve it. The error is occuring when I import stuff that references tastypie hence i can't modify it. I appreciate your time to look at this. The code where the error is ocurring in the resources file is:

```
from models import *
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource


# Resources specific for structures and are location based.
class NotificationResource (ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Notification.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

And in my installed application settings I have this.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'tastypie',

    #Local Apps 
    'useraccounts',
)
```

Comment: have you try tu put tastypie at the top in your INSTALLED_APPS ?
Also what does the useraccount model looks like? and have you created it's resource?

Comment: @nnaelle thanks for the reply I placed the tastypie app at the top but no change and my Person model looks like shown below: 
class Person(AbstractUser):

    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)

    secret_answer = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    # Use UserManager to get the create_user method, etc.
    objects = PersonModelManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'


    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name

Comment: Have you tried creating the Person resource in your tastypie file?
Where do you import username_field? could be a case sensitive issue maybe?

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Prydie please try the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I immersed my hands into the tastypie code and added

```
username_field ='username'
```

after line 19. Its a bug being caused by the fact that no reference to the username object is found if the improperly configured error occurs.

Comment: I actually managed to fix it without modifying TastyPie. Basically it came down to where I added the post_save signal. It needs to be in code that is ran AFTER the custom user code so that TastyPie can import the module and define the field.

Comment: That seems to be the correct thing to do I will also try changing my app that way thanks @Prydie